# Android Studio Method getCurrentPosition must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use VideoProgress to develop the video from async task and get this error
Method getCurrentPosition must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker.

```
public class VideoProgress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){


        do{
            if(isPlaying) {
                current = vv.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                publishProgress(current);
            }
        }while (currentProgress.getProgress() <= 100);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        try {
            int currentPercent = values[0] * 100/duration;
            currentProgress.setProgress(currentPercent);
            String currentString = String.format("%02d:%02d", values[0] / 60, values[0] % 60);
            curTime.setText(currentString);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }



}
```

How can I fix the error?Thank.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute UI components from background thread. You either need to use runOnUIThread or Handler.

You can do following:

```
if(isPlaying) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 current = vv.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;   
            }
        });
...
}
```

**OR**

```
if(isPlaying) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            current = vv.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
        }
    });
...
}
```